# Multiple partials means that model errors bleed between forms

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two partials on a page, both are have forms in them.

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("LogIn", Model.EmailAuthenticationViewModel);
    Html.RenderPartial("Register", Model.RegistrationViewModel);
}@
```

When I submit a form in an error state (e.g. no email address), the validation errors appear on both partials.

How can I restrict validation errors to only the errors caused by that partial?

*For example*

Both partials have a field for an email address.  When one of the partial's forms is submitted without the email address, the validation error appears on *both* form's input boxes.

Both forms define the text box in the standard manner:

```
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)

            <div class="validation-summary-error" role="alert">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a different form for each or is it the same one?

Comment: Different form, but same names, e.g. both the partials forms have an email field.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is very similar to this question: [Specify validation summary on multiple forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342427/specify-validation-summary-on-multiple-forms).

Mandoleen shared this blog post [Multiple validation summary at single page](http://mahaafifi.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/multiple-validation-summary-at-single.html).

Please check and tell us if it doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking (though it feels like a hack), I was just looking at how to set the Temp data via JavaScript.

Comment: What do you mean by "Temp" data? Is your problem fixed?

Comment: TempData is session data that only lasts for one session.

Comment: Did you try [this other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17804804/1635807) without the hack?

Comment: This isn't really a solution in partials as you've have to keep them globally unique.  I can see that erupting into ikkiness.

Comment: In fact you shouldn't have too many forms on your page, and at least max. one per type. So you can call your partial forms like "form-login" and "form-register". Of course put those names as a `static readonly string` and reuse this string in your action.